# Problem doing this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin(4x) \,dx$$

Doing $U$ substitution I get:

$$\left[\frac{1}{4} \left(- \cos(4x) \right)\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

From which I get $0$ but the correct answer is $1/2$ where is my error?

Comment: What substitution did you use?

Comment: The substitution is U = 4x

Comment: -(-1/4)-(-1/4)=1/2

Comment: @Adithya where does the first minus comes from?

Comment: @VOZESTOICA Look at your expression. The minus infront of the cos.

Comment: Aahhh sorry the calculator was going me 1 for Cos of pi 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your antiderivative is correct. Then it is $$ (-1/4)(\cos(\pi)-cos(0))=(-1/4)(-1-1)=1/2.$$